# TypeScript can't find name forEach

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use forEach in my TypeScipt program as follow:

```
const treeForEachDF: <T>(f: Command<T>, tree: Tree<T>)=>void =
(f, tree) => {
    f(tree.root);
    if (!treeLeaf(tree))
        forEach(x => treeForEachDF(f, x), treeChildren(tree));
};
```

However, I get the following error:

"TS2304 cannot find name 'forEach'"

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "module": "commonjs",
   "target": "es5",
   "noImplicitAny": false,
   "sourceMap": false,
     "types": [
        "node"
     ],
     "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
     ]
},
    "exclude": [
    "lib/startup.ts",
    "node_modules/",
    "typings/"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I assume you want to run `treeForEachDF` on every object in `treeChildren(tree)`. Did you try: `treeChildren(tree).forEach(child => treeForEachDF(f, child));`?

Comment: Just a bit of code review, maybe `runCommandOnTree` will be a clearer name. Think about people looking at usage 6 months from now... They'll definitely enjoy seeing `runCommandOnTree` instead of `treeForEachDF`

Comment: what are the data types you are using there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a way to use forEach as I tried in the first place, when importing it from 'ramda' as follow:

```
import {map, reduce, forEach} from 'ramda'
```